# What is the isomorphism map between $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z[x] / (x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, ring-isomorphism

What is the isomorphism map between $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z[x] / (x).$?

I am trying to prove that the ideal $(x)$ is a prime ideal and to show this, I want to show that $\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z[x] / (x),$ I do not know how to write this isomorphism, could someone help me, please?

Also, I do not know how to show that it is not a maximal ideal, could someone show me this please?

Comment: Construct a surjective ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ with kernel $(x)$ and use the power of the isomorphism theorems. There is an obvious map that sends $x$ to zero...

Comment: Try $a+(x)\to a$

Comment: If you prove the quotient is $\mathbb{Z}$, that proves it is not maximal, as $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field.

Comment: hint for the non-maximality: What do you have to quotient by to make it a field? Can you add that missing something to your ideal?

Comment: Hint: the homomorphism $\mathbb Z[x]\mapsto \mathbb Z$ sending $p(x)\mapsto p(0)$ has $(x)$ as the kernel.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin what do you mean by the power of isomorphism theorems?

Comment: Did you mean to say that $a$ is the evaluation of the polynomial $p$ at $0$?

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger for your first question, I have to quotient by all $\mathbb Z$ except $0$ and $1,$ I do not know how to write this.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews but I want an isomorphism $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z[x] / (x)$ instead not just between  $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z[x],$ how will I get from your isomorphism to mine?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think I got the answer below, thanks!!

Comment: I meant that you should use the isomorphism theorems, which are powerful tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ideal $\mathscr I\subset \mathcal R$ is prime iff $\mathcal R/\mathscr I$ is an integral domain. Apparently you knew that.

Consider the evaluation homomorphism:  $\rm{ev_0}:\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb Z$ by $\rm{ev_0}(p)=p(0)$.

$(x)=\rm{ker}(\rm{ev_0})$,  because $x$ is the minimal polynomial of $0$.  Also $\rm{ev_0}$ is surjective.

Now by the first isomorphism theorem we get $$\Bbb Z[x]/(x)\cong\Bbb Z$$.

Two things: since $\Bbb Z$ is an integral domain,  $(x)$ is a prime ideal.

Second, $\Bbb Z$ an integral domain $\implies \Bbb Z[x]$ is an integral domain.   Then since the quotient of $\Bbb Z[x]$ by $(x)$ is not a field, $(x)$ is not maximal.

Alternatively on the second part,  $\Bbb Z[x]\supsetneq(2,x)\supsetneq (x)$.  This may seem confusing,  since $2$ and $x$ are relatively prime.   But we don't have Bezout,  because $\Bbb Z[x]$ isn't a PID.

Comment: What do you mean by saying $x$ is the minimal polynomial of $0$?

Comment: It's the monic polynomial of least positive degree such that $p(0)=0$.